# Поиск нулей в двумерном массиве

Tags: массивы, pascal

Дан массив, например такой

```
0 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Требуется вывести номер ряда,где больше всего нулей. В массиве могу присутствовать только единицы или нули. Вот мой код,но программа работает не правильно.Помогите понять,где я допустил ошибку.

```
var
  i,j,n,m,max,l:integer;
  A:array [1..100,1..100] of integer;
begin
   readln(n);
   readln(m);
   for i:=1 to n do  begin
     for j:=1 to m do begin
       read(A[i,j]);
       if A[i,j]=0  then
         l:=l+1;
       if l > max then
         max:=i;
     end;
   end;
   writeln(max);
end.
```

Comment: не совсем понимаю,как реализовать пункт 3, в задаче ещё говорится,что таких рядов может быть несколько,где одинаковое количество рядов и нужно вывести номер рядя меньшего по порядку

Comment: а само заполнение массива где у вас??

Comment: @Ale_x, `read(A[i,j])` не?

Answer (score 1):

```
var
  i, j, n, m: Integer;
  RowWithMaxZeroes: Integer;
  MaxZeroesInRow: Integer;
  ZeroesInRow: Integer;
  A: array [1..100, 1..100] of Integer;
begin
    ReadLn(n);
    {Здесь нужно проверить, что n не больше 100 и что-то сделать, если оно больше}
    ReadLn(m);
    {Здесь нужно проверить, что m не больше 100 и что-то сделать, если оно больше}
    RowWithMaxZeroes := 0;
    MaxZeroesInRow := 0;
    for i := 1 to n do
    begin
      ZeroesInRow := 0;
      for j := 1 to m do
      begin
        Read(A[i, j]);
        if A[i, j] = 0  then
          ZeroesInRow := ZeroesInRow + 1;
      end;
      if ZeroesInRow > MaxZeroesInRow then
      begin
        MaxZeroesInRow := ZeroesInRow;
        RowWithMaxZeroes := i;
      end;
    end;
    WriteLn('Row with max zeroes: ', RowWithMaxZeroes);
end.
```

После ввода `m` и `n` хорошо бы проверить, что они не больше 100 :)

P.S.: `l` плохое имя для переменной, оно путается с `i`.

Comment: если max - это номер строки, почему вы его сравниваете с количеством 0?

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, что спросили. Это я скопипастил кусок кода из вопроса не подумав. Исправил код в своем ответе. Теперь мухи отдельно от котлет =)

Comment: ага, я уже потом тоже увидел, в вопросе так же :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Перед проходом по ряду надо обнулять переменную l
2. Проверять максимальное ли количество l после прохода по рядку
3. Если это максимум то надо запомнить еще номер ряда, чтобы его потом вывести